# can I download whatsapp on my windowsphone?

Tags: whatsapp

I need to communicate with my family and also it makes everything simple nowadays I need whatsapp but for a better use.

Comment: Did you look in the store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.. Click **[this link](https://www.whatsapp.com/wp/)** on your mobile phone, and it will automatically take you to the application's page in the Store application.

Alternatively, you can visit www.whatsapp.com from your mobile phone's browser, and you will be welcomed with this page:

[image]

Click on the green download button, and it will take you to the store from where you can install the application.

Comment: Yes I did enter in store and than I tried to download whatsapp but the phone didn't download whatsapp why?

Comment: What was the problem. Did it show any error message when it failed to download